# remove all file types from dir not working

Tags: find

My dir is as following:

Music: 1.mp3, 2.flac, 3.wav, 4.ogg and 5.mp4

I'm trying to remove all files with extensions: .mp3, .wav, .flac and .ogg with the following command:

```
find ./Music -type f -name \('*.mp3' -or -name '*.wav' -or -name '*.flac' -or -name '*.ogg'\) -delete
```

but it's doing nothing to the directory

any idea why?

(i'm one level higher than the Music dir btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong. You want all the `-name` options in the same parentheses, and a space around the parentheses, like this:

```
find ./Music -type f  \( -name '*.mp3' -or -name '*.wav' -or -name '*.flac' -or -name '*.ogg' \) -delete
```

Your original command was using `-name \('*.mp3' -or -name '*.wav' -or -name '*.flac' -or -name '*.ogg'\)` which means it was looking for files named `\(*.mp3`, or `'*.wav'` or `'*.flac'` or `'*.ogg'\)`. You can see this if you run the command without the `-delete` option:

```
$ find ./Music -type f -name \('*.mp3' -or -name '*.wav' -or -name '*.flac' -or -name '*.ogg'\) 
./Music/3.wav
./Music/2.flac
```

Since there are no matches for `\('*.mp3'` or `*.ogg\)`, those files were not found. And since you hadn't grouped the command in parentheses (you need spaces around the parentheses for that to work), the `-delete` wasn't applied as you expected (sorry, I don't know exactly how `find` would have parsed that).

Comment: _and_ is grouped more tightly than _or_, so you'd have had `find ./Music \( -type f -name '(*.mp3' \) -or \( -name '*.wav' \) -or \( -name '*.flac' \) -or \( -name '*.ogg)' -delete \)`, where I've added the implicit precedence brackets. Notice that the result is effectively a series of no-ops except for deleting files _or directories_ matching the final `*.ogg)` pattern

Comment: Also, if `./Music` is a symbolic link, they may have to use `find -H ./Music ...` to resolve it, or `find ./Music/ ...`.

Comment: Thank you, also thanks for explaining!